# Jasper Report won't work in JAR file but works fine while developing

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I have project structure like this

```
- RootFolder
    - Frame
        - Finance
            - Budgeting.java
    - Reports
        - ReportBudgeting.jrxml
```

I am using Jasper iReports for reporting. While in NetBeans it works fine. I have included all of the classpaths too. I think the issue where I call the ***.jrxml** file from ***.java file**. I called it like this:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/Budgeting.jrxml");
JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(inputStream);
JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
```

And I got errors like this:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.net.MalformedURLException
> at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader.loadXML

How can I fixed this?

This is my build configuration
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'll need to post your entire build configuration, but if I had to guess, I'm betting that during the compilation phase of your project, resources might need to be located in a different source folder. For example, maven resources need to be in src/main/resources by default in order to make into the final jar.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Before I post my entire build config, I have a question. Is Java Application must put all of files and folders inside src/<ProjectName>/ ? Example, if my project name is Budget then all of the folder, like Frame/ or Reports/ that i have mentioned earlier must be under src/Budget/ ?

Answer (score 0):

In a standard Java application, all your code and resource files should be within the src directory, at least is you don't wanna deal with situations like yours anymore. So if your project name is Budget, your structure ideally would look like:

```
- Budget
    - src
        - main
            - java
                - Frame
                    - Finance
                        - Budgeting.java
            - resources
                - Reports
                    - ReportBudgeting.jrxml
```

so this row should finally work:

```java
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/Budgeting.jrxml");
```

(assuming that /Reports/Budgeting.jrxml is relative to the classpath (and in our case, it should be src/main/resources))

Comment: I need to refactor all of my project structure first at least. Thank you. I want to do this first.

Answer (score 0):

Try just "filename", it's part of the configuration settings immutable enumeration of resources.
If it should be notified in e.g. server.xml settings , it may be getSystemResources is the method required and it returns an **enumeration of  keyname , URL** . The one you are using may be String "name" just straight to resource with its keyname (just file name). Also, the web XML may contain jrxml in "development" mode setting.
Note, probably "name" is file as keyname, URL are "path section" in the enumeration.